# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Run time error :

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Query :

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.[BPOFmv], 0) AS BPOFmv FROM [MyTables] as a
```

Records of `a.[BPOFmv]` column as shown below.

```
 $125,000 
 $145,000 
 209000 
 63,000
```

Question :

I think the issue here is `$` mark.Can you tell me how to remove it ? I'm going to insert these values into `decimal(18, 2)` column.

Comment: You have an specific data type for this in SQL: money

Comment: @Oscar Good to hear about it.But we cannot change data types now.It is `decimal(18,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the REPLACE function

```
    SELECT ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.[BPOFmv], '$',''),',',''), 0) AS BPOFmv 
FROM [MyTables]
```

You can CAST it into a format too if you wish

```
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.[BPOFmv], '$',''),',',''), 0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS BPOFmv 
FROM [MyTables]
```

Comment: Can you tell me the differences of two options ?

Comment: One just casts to the correct DEICMAL(18,2) as you specified. No big deal in either, maybe use the first option if working with large data.

Comment: I have used 2nd option.Thanks :)